# Cannot vertically align 2 TextViews within a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview, android-layout-weight

I have a calendar image (72x72). I am trying to overlay the month on the top bit and the day date on the main bit.

I'm trying to do this by using a vertical LinearLayout with the calendar set as the background image with two TextViews as the children of the LinearLayout.

I've got it working up to a point, but I cannot get the month to move down sufficiently so that it is in the correct position.

This image is what I've achieved so far:

[image: Incorrect Calendar Image]

Using the following layout fragment:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="8">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="September"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingBottom="-10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:text="21"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've been playing around with weight and padding (as you can see), but nothing I've tried has worked.

Can anyone suggest what I should do? (I'd prefer not to change the text sizes if possible.)

The answer was to add padding to the top of the date month TextView as Hussein El Feky (and Brendan Shaenzer) suggested. So thank you, both.

Here is the corrected image:

[image: Correct Calendar Image]

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the TextView is occupying this much space when you actually given it 3/8 weight. Is it because of the style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/cal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="September"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:text="21"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you can provide your cal drawable, I will also be able to improve my answer. I have let your TextViews be centered, but now play with the weights, since I don't have your drawable.

Comment: Hi, don't know how to add an image in comments but it is 72x72 and the red/white border is at 30 so weights would be 1 to 1.4.  I think it is a problem of padding/margins/ll dividers and I need to do soe more investigating .  I was hoping there might be a simple solution :(

Comment: If your red part starts from 0 to 30 (30) and your white part starts from 30 to 72 (42) then layout weights should look like 30:42 simplified to 5:7. I have updated my answer. Only thing you should do now is adding paddingTop to your first TextView (Month) and adjust it to that two white rectangles at the top. If you need more help, tell me.

Comment: Yes, adding paddingtop sorted it out.  It extended the background image slightly but I could adjust that to something acceptable by resizing the date day textsize.  Many thanks, I've added the corrected image to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need space between the first `TextView` and the top of the `LinearLayout`, but I don't see any attributes in there that would achieve that. Any of:

- `android:paddingTop` on `textView8`
- `android:layout_marginTop` on `textView8`
- `android:paddingTop` on the `LinearLayout`

Should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I think you are right but I need to do some more experimenting.  As I said in a previous comment, I was hoping that there might be some simple solution.